# Setting particular program for opening hyperlink in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hyperlink, jpeg-2000

I have some hyperlinks set up in ArcGIS for Desktop which, when accessed, open a small mobile mapping JPEG file.

Currently the images open in the default windows photo viewer but I would like for them to open in a different program which we have personalised for these JPEG files. The JPEG files are from a 360 degree ladybug system and the normal windows photo viewer isn't suitable for viewing them. Hence the need to use the personalised program.

Is there a way to set a different program for opening the hyperlink other than setting a default program in windows? I have to send the data/mxd to a client and didn't really want them adjusting their default windows settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that I recall having ever done myself but I suspect that what you are looking for is the Script radio button that is mentioned under [Using Hyperlinks](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-layers/using-hyperlinks.htm):

> **Script** — When you click a feature with the Hyperlink tool, a feature value is sent to a script. This option enables the use of
>   customized behavior.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about scripts yet but I'll take a look :)

Appreciate the help!